# Perl Net::Google::Calendar event occurrence

Tags: perl, google-calendar-api

I have the following code ( perl ), but I"m not sure how to extract the occurrence events ?

```
use Net::Google::Calendar;



my @cals = $parent->get_calendars;

for my $cal_selected (@cals) {

        printf "CALENDAR: %s\n", $cal_selected->title;

        $parent->set_calendar( $cal_selected );

                for ( $parent->get_events() ) {
                        my $title = $_->title || "";
                        my ($start, $end) = $_->when();

                        print "title: $title, start: $start, end: $end \n";
                }
}
```

So, one of the events has a "start" var, but it jump every 4 days - and I don't see it in my current output.

Output looks like this:

```
title: "Event 1", start: 2012-08-06T00:00:00, end: 2012-08-13T00:00:00 
title: "Event 2", start: 2012-07-05T00:00:00, end: 2012-07-05T00:00:00
```

"Event1" has a very clear start and end dates, 6 days ..

See that "Event 2" is at the same day, but the occurances are at 2012-07-05, 2012-07-09, 2012-07-13
But I don't see that in the output itself ...

Comment: Please show the output and what you mean by "jump". What should the calendar or the events be like?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what the problem is. Have you looked at the [recurrence](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Google-Calendar/lib/Net/Google/Calendar/Entry.pm#recurrence_[_Data::ICal::Entry::Event_])-method of the `Net::Google::Calendar::Entry` object?

Comment: Tried all possible variations ... it's always returns empty result .. also tried $_->recorrance->as_string; which died somewhere in the script ... not sure how to use this function ...

Comment: I've tried it as well. The only thing I can get is the title on all my events. Or some, at least. I don't know what it uses to filter them. I do not get any `DateTime`-Objects, nor anything on recurrence. But when I say `$_->content->body` I at least get to peak at some HTML. There might have been some changes on Google's side that broke the parser, though that is just a guess.

Comment: Something else: I remember this has worked for me once, but I do not have the code any more. I tried to create entries, which I'm sure worked.

Comment: When you create an entry and you hold the $var, you can see the occurrence, but if you extract the events from gmail - you don't ... not sure what's the difference ... but it's really not working for me, any other thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

You might need try the `recurrence` method. The problem is that if you use this and you don't have the `Data::ICal` module installed, you'll get an `undef`instead of an error. Unfortunately, you'll also get an `undef` if you have `Data::ICal` installed, and there's no reoccurrence. That's just bad module programming.

The recurrence method returns an [Data::Ical::Entry::Event](http://search.cpan.org/~tsibley/Data-ICal/lib/Data/ICal/Entry/Event.pm) object.

From there, I'm not entirely sure what to do. The `Data::ICal::Entry::Event` documentation is really sparse. I had to read through the [iCalendar RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) which mentioned that this field is stored in something called `rdate`. There's a mention of multiple `rdate` properties in the `Data::ICal::Entry::Event` module, but nothing that says how to access it, or what format it's in.

I think you're suppose to use [Data::ICal::DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~simonw/Data-ICal-DateTime-0.7/lib/Data/ICal/DateTime.pm) to help parse this information. This module has a reoccurrence method that allows you to pull out the *union* of all rdates. Unfortunately, it uses an `Data::ICal` object, and you have an `Data::ICal::Entry::Event` object. Maybe that's a subclass of `Data::ICal`, so maybe it'll still work.

Unfortunately, I don't have Google Calendar setup, so I really have no way of playing around with this. Sorry about not being more definite about this. However, I hope this leads you the right way.

---

One more recommendation: Use [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) to dump out the various objects you're getting. This will help you understand what's going on and how information is stored in these objects. With a bit of luck, you'll be able to figure out exactly what methods and modules you need to get the information you want.

It's not polite to peek, but when you don't understand the question, looking up the answer in back of the book can sometimes help.

Comment: @Ricky. You put `use Data::Dumper;` at the top of your program, then You simply call `Dumper` on the object in question: `print Dumper $parent . "\n";`. This will print out all the elements in the object and give you the class the object belongs to.